# Sed for replacing pattern

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I would like to replace a pattern, which consist of a var surrounded by `()` with `sed`. The next command success :

```
echo "This is the pattern : th_now(5, almost done!" | sed "s/th_now($var/th_now_$var/g"
```

But when I try to used the correct pattern in which I am interested it fails :

```
echo "This is the pattern : th_now(5), almost done!" | sed "s/th_now($var)/th_now_$var/g"
```

There is a way to solve it ?
thank you.

Comment: Welcome, what would be the expected result and what is `$var`?

Comment: $var in this case is 5, it can be any number. So, when it is th_now(6) it will be transform to th_now_6

Comment: `$var` would be a variable external to the command `sed`, so you would have to define it before. What do you mean that the first command succeeds?

Comment: With success I mean the first command return : This is the pattern : th_now_5, almost done!, so it was not necessary to define $var before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think this is what you are looking for:

```sh
$ echo "This is the pattern : th_now(5), almost done!" | sed 's/th_now(\([^()]*\))/th_now_\1/'
This is the pattern : th_now_5, almost done!
```

Or:

```sh
$ echo "This is the pattern : th_now(5), almost done!" | sed 's/th_now(\([[:digit:]]*\))/th_now_\1/'
This is the pattern : th_now_5, almost done!
```

Comment: perfect !, both solutions match what I need. Definitely, I feel grateful with your fast and precise help.

Comment: Just and additional question to complement the previous one, if I need to replace : echo "This is the pattern : th_now(8,5,6,x,y,z) almost done!" | sed 's/th_now(\([^()]*\))/th_now_\1/' | sed 's/,/_/g' , I need to used two sed commands, there is way to use only one ??

Comment: The idea is to replace th_now(8,5,6,x,y,z) with th_now_8_5_6_x_y_z or any number of parameters inside the ( ). For example th_now(1,2,a) with th_now_1_2_a. With the previous sentence I can do, but I need to use two sed commands, there is a better way to do this replacement, using only one sed command?

Comment: @CGeorgi if you have a new requirement please post it as a separate question

Comment: @CGeorgi `| awk -F '\\(|\\)' '{gsub(/,/,"_",$2); printf "%s_%s%s\n", $1, $2, $3}'`, you could always slice the string with `awk` where you use the parentheses as delimiters.